# Infinite sum of the reciprocal of "anti-primorials"

Tags: sequences-and-series, primorial

Multiple questions have been submitted regarding the sum of the reciprocal of primorials, i.e.

$$
S_P=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot3} + \frac{1}{2\cdot3\cdot5} + \ldots \approx 0.7052301717918\ldots
$$

I got curious what this would look like if we define an "anti-primorial" $A_n$ to be the product of the $n$ first *non-primes*, and calculate the sum of their reciprocals:

$$
S_A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4\cdot6} + \frac{1}{4\cdot6\cdot8} + \ldots \approx 0.29751676555\ldots
$$

The first thing that jumps to the eye is that the sum of these 2 values is quite close to 1 (or 2, if you include 1 in the "anti-primorials"):

$$
S_P + S_A \approx 1.0027469\ldots
$$

Now this may well be a "coincidence" due to the first few biggest factors happening to have the right values, but I was wondering if perhaps someone would have some deeper insight on why this pattern might arise. Thanks.